# Failed to start post-commit hook

Tags: python, svn, bash

I'm struggling to get a subversion post commit hook to work.

When I commit, I get the error:

```
Failed to start '/svn/web/hooks/post-commit' hook
```

I read around a bit with people that had similar problems, and they all related to the lack of environment, or incorrect file permissions, so I ran this:

```
sudo -u www-data env - ./post-commit /svn/web 70
```

But it worked fine!  I added logging to the file, which works when I run it with the above command, but not when I commit to the repo.

Any ideas?  I gave everyone execute permission (`chmod a+x post-commit`).

Comment: Can you post an example of some code that isn't working?

Comment: **[This post-commit](http://trac-hacks.org/svn/timingandestimationplugin/branches/trac0.12/scripts/svn-post-commit.sh)** which hits **[this python script](http://trac-hacks.org/svn/timingandestimationplugin/branches/trac0.12/scripts/trac-post-commit.py)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my line endings.

```
 fromdos post-commit
```

Did the trick.